# Is it possible to combine CPUID and Instruction set emulation arguments in Intel SDE

Tags: x86, emulation, intel, instruction-set, cpuid

Running `sde.exe -nhm -bmi1 1 -- TestConsole.exe` command don't take into account the `-bmi1 1` option.
It emulates `nhm` instruction set correctly but doesn't emulate the `bmi1` instruction set.
Is it possible to combine them some other way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately its not possible to combine both arguments as mentioned [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-isa-extensions/topic/844281#comment-1952039).
But there is an alternative to specify custom CPUID definition file as mentioned [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-isa-extensions/topic/844281#comment-1952090) and emulate only the specific instruction sets.